# What is the simplest way to disable multisite leaving one of the sites only?

Tags: multisite

I developed different versions of a wordpress site using multisite. Now I need to use only the second version out of three, that is blog_id=2 which is also pointed to a mydomain.com/dir2.

What is the easiest way to disable multisite while leaving blog_id=2 pointing directly to mydomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default export plugin and use a new install, Single mode. Import the XML file and done. All other options have more todos and risk.

Comment: Indeed it was the easiest way to do it. Just wanted to add that it is also necessary to move the structure of wp-content/uploads/sites into wp-content/uploads/